# Terraserver replacment - source for US Topo maps?

Tags: data, wms, topography

Now that Terraserver has been shut down (or at least that's how it appears), is there an alternative WMS server for US topo maps? Probably too much to hope to find one that provides vector layers rather than rasters.

About a year ago [this similar question appeared](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8977/site-to-download-al-usgs-topo-maps-in-bulk) (actually bulk download of topo maps), but back then Terraserver was still in operation and appeared in several of the answers.

Answer (score 3):

If I read correctly, you are looking for a replacement for the WMS service of the USGS Quad Maps.  From what I can find, there doesn't seem to be a direct replacement for that.  I think the closest you are likely to find is using the [Seamlesss Data Warehouse](http://seamless.usgs.gov/).  This is the USGS data portal for all the orthoimagery that they supply as well as their National Elevation Dataset layers, in various resolutions.  These represent some of the raw data used in the Topos, so there would be additional processing necessary.

The link to the area that has the WMS Service information is here:  [Link](http://seamless.usgs.gov/services.php)

I can't immediately find vector information there that is available as a WMS, however you are able to download Places, Transportation, Boundaries, Hydrography, etc. through the Seamless site.  I suppose in the future, they could add additional layers as WMS or even WFS services in that section of the website.

Hope this helps!

Comment: While some portion of the content of the topo maps is available from the Seamless Data Warehouse, I'm definitely not interested in creating my own topo maps from the source data. That would be a massive undertaking. The USGS is in the process of reissuing the familiar 7.5' quads and even they are facing challenges of identifying digital sources for some of the information on the old print maps. (For example, the current generation of GeoPDFs don't have trails on them).