# Are there Python packages for Landsat 8 processing?

Tags: python, remote-sensing, landsat, landsat-8, pymodis

While there are a number of python projects for MODIS acquisition and processing (pyModis and get_modis), I have yet to encounter a toolset for automating Landsat 8 processing in Python. There's discussion of [GRASS-based approaches](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67657/open-source-solutions-for-landsat-8-mosaicing-and-correction), and of challenges related to [automated downloading](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72816/is-there-a-programmatic-way-to-retrieve-landsat-8-satellite-images), but I'm curious if anyone's come across Python processing options. My functionality wish list would include items similar to what GRASS offers:

- data acquisition and import
- Auto-enhance colors, natural color composites
- Calculate Top-of-Atmosphere Reflectance and band-6 Temperature
- Haze removal
- Atmospheric correction
- Cloud identification
- image classification
- Export of results

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just thought I'd add that there are some 'pure' Python solutions for several nodes in this workflow, also.

Some file reading and basic processing:

Spectral Python: http://spectralpython.sourceforge.net/

More classification than you'll find in pure remote sensing and GIS packages:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/

More links I can't share:
6S Python atmospheric correction, Shapely, gdal bindings for reading geoTIFF (relatively trivial to parse metadata from Landsat 8 and read all images into a cube). There are other processing options in SciPy general and MDP (modular data processing, too).

Answer (score 7):

If you really want to use python, and you need functionality similar to GRASS, perhaps the easiest solution would be to use [GRASS via Python](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Python).

That isn't specific to Landsat8, but I don't think a processing solution should be tied that closely to a specific satellite. You could implement some simple wrappers / higher level functions if you're consistently performing the same operations.

Side note: on "Cloud identification", remember that Landsat8 has a specific sensor for this (Band 9 on OLI) so that should be pretty trivial.