# Java packages for landsat 8 processing?

Tags: java, remote-sensing, landsat, landsat-8

I am looking for the same packages as outlined in this question - [Are there Python packages for Landsat 8 processing?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78598/are-there-python-packages-for-landsat-8-processing) except that I want these in Java. Any Open Source packages out there that can do the same processing in Java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably lean to GRASS for this, irrespective of the language you want to access it from.

General LANDSAT discussion for GRASS: http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/LANDSAT

[Marcus Neteler](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/687/markusn) has provided some extra guidance on the Landsat8 import and processing: http://courses.neteler.org/processing-landsat8-data-in-grass-gis-7/

Once you have the data understood, call it from Java using one of the methods at http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Java

Comment: I've had trouble getting Grass 7 to run on Ubuntu 14. Is QGIS as useful as Grass for Landsat 8 processing?

Comment: @BradHards - How about JGrass ? http://udig.refractions.net/gallery/jgrass/

Comment: JGrass is also a possibility, but its more of an application, and I understood you were looking for a java programming approach. This is all free software, so you can try various options.

Comment: @BradHards - If I can avoid calling a process within my Java code that would be good enough.

Comment: That would have been good information to put in the question...

Comment: @BradHards - No issues. Your answer is still very good. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

Google Earth Engine can process Landsat 8 data using Java code and I believe it is free.
https://earthengine.google.com