# Programmatically Downloading Landsat Images

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat

There was a very similar question to this one [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72816/is-there-a-programmatic-way-to-retrieve-landsat-8-satellite-images/90375#90375)
, but it specified Landsat 8 images; I'd just like to be able to download ANY landsat images, given latitude and longitudes as inputs.

Just wanted to see if anyone knew of something that does this already, although I don't hold much hope.

I'm thinking of writing an application that uses usgs's Earth Explorer tool, but I don't have much experience with writing applications that make HTTP requests and such. If someone could at least help in going down this path, it would be something.

I don't necessarily have any preference where language is concerned, but for what it's worth I'm writing the rest of the related software in C++. I've looked around at various sources of satellite imagery and other spatial data, but everything I've found falls into either of two categories; 1) it's a website that allows you to search for datasets/images and download them individually, or 2) is integrated into a GIS software system and doesn't appear to have any information for developers looking to do do this integration themselves.

Ideally, I'd like something like google earth's static maps API, where I just specify latitude and longitude and I get the an image corresponding to my input. However, I don't want pretty pictures, I want geographic data, including data that I can't get from google earth (anything that's not visible light imagery).

I'm getting away from the question-answer format of SE (I was mostly asking whether there were any existing solutions for automatically retrieving satellite imagery) but I might as well tell you my intent with all this; I'm trying to write software that reads in a variety of geographic data (imagery, height, temperature, etc) and attempts to classify the terrain into types (such as forest, grassland,  ocean, etc). I'm not looking at a specific area; it's a general method and the software should be able to pull data from arbitrary locations.

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. To help us give you an answer that might be useful, can you update your question (just click edit below the question) with which language(s) might be suitable. Also, including details of anything that you've already tried, and what research you've already done, might help us tell you things you don't already know, rather than already seen/tried. You should also have linked to the existing question.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest that you take a look at https://github.com/olivierhagolle/LANDSAT-Download
That tool can download either given a single set of coordinates, or a WRS-2 grid number. It's based on python. It does require a earthexplorer login, but those are free, so it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use some tools from Development Seed (a company directly related to MapBox)

This year they made available [Landsat-util](https://github.com/developmentseed/landsat-util) to download and process data from Landsat 8 images. You just have to be aware that it can do more than downloading Landsat images: it also help to process them. In this case, you will need a powerful computer.

To learn more, just take a look at [this blog post](http://www.developmentseed.org/blog/2014/08/29/landsat-util/).

Answer (score 1):

The python tool [Landsat578](https://github.com/dgketchum/Landsat578) does this.

Landsat578 recently was updated to download from Google Cloud's public Landsat catalog, meaning no credentials are needed.  This project is under active maintenance. I've tested it on Landsat 5, 7, and 8 downloads, though it should be able to download earlier Landsat data as well, as it is in the catalog.

`pip install Landsat578`

An example, using decimal degree coordinates:

`landsat -sat 7 --start 2007-05-01 --end 2007-05-31 --lat 46.5 --lon -107.5 -o /path/to/folder`

Or if the path and row are known:

`landsat -sat 7 --start 2007-05-01 --end 2007-05-31 --path 38 --row 27 -o /path/to/folder`

There are other options, such as return list of avialable images without downloading, etc.

`landsat` will give all optional parameters.

The first use of this tool will download and unzip a large metadata file that could take a few minutes.